# show url into console with node.js

Tags: node.js

how can i display the request.url into the console.log to see, which url someone called?
So i want to see into console for each call a line with the url.

Sorry, i'm a very beginner with node.js ;-)
Thanks for help.

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8083; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
    console.log("URL:%s");
});
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the answer, "Put `console.log(request.url)` inside your `handleResponse` function"?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using express you can setup a custom middleware, that gets called for every request.

```js
// logging middleware
var num = 0;
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    var method = req.method;
    var url = req.url;

    console.log((++num) + ". IP " + ip + " " + method + " " + url);
    next();
});
```

But you can do the same with your http module server :)

Comment: fyi console.log accepts multiple arguments: console.log(ip,method,url)